# State coming to be default and not updated one in react

Tags: reactjs

So, react is show me the old state.

I have this code

```
const Users = () => {
    const { rightSideBarState, setRightSideBarState } = React.useContext(RightSidebarContext);
    const { setHeaderState } = React.useContext(HeaderContext);
    const [active, setActive] = React.useState<string | null>(null);
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = React.useState<string>('');
    const [userData, setUserData] = React.useState<User.UserData[]>([]);

    console.log('user Data:', userData);

    const onAddingNewUser = async (services: User.SucessfulInvitationSent[], email: string) => {
        console.log('EmaiL:', email, userData);
  
    };

    const { refetch } =
        useQuery([`users`], () => getUsersData(searchText).then((data) => setUserData(data)), {
            suspense: true,
        }) ?? [];

    const onAddUserClicked = () => {
        setRightSideBarState({
            visible: true,
            rightSidebarDisplay: {
                headerTitle: 'Add Users',
                headerCloseAction: () => {
                    setRightSideBarState({ visible: false });
                    setActive('');
                },
                content: <RightSidebarCreateUser onAddingNewUser={onAddingNewUser} />,
            },
        });
    };
```

Here, `console.log('user Data:', userData);` this shows correct value but  `console.log('EmaiL:', email, userData);` is coming out to be the default value i.e empty array.

Can someone help me in understanding why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Do you have a codesandbox or Github repo link?

Comment: Or at least provide code for `RightSidebarContext` please?